# Как открыть одну страницу для всех slug-ов

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть файл page-menu.php который открывается по адресу `site.ru/menu`.

Как открыть эту же страницу, если `site.ru/menu/slug`? Я хочу `slug` использовать как фильтр.

Comment: если честно, то я не очень понял что вы хотите. можете как-то конкретнее и на примерах объяснить что вы хотите, что вы пробовали делать и что у вас не получается?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Фильтр, слаги?!! Налицо [ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/233741)

Comment: @МихаилРебров по URL site.ru/menu открывается файл page-menu.php с статичным контентом, если URL например  site.ru/menu/buger то 404 ошибка. 
Мне надо чтобы если URL site.ru/menu/buger или любой другой, то открывалась тоже файл page-menu.php

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасбо